# Browser is showing Javascript code instead of processing it

Tags: javascript

Currently I've tried this process with two browsers: Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. Whenever I want to run a JavaScript code on them they show me the raw code instead of executing it. Exactly what I wrote in my Editor will be shown in the browser screen.

Hope someone can help.

### Edit

> Hey, am not using wordpress.

Sorry that I didn't put the code here. Here is
the code in my text Editor:

```
<Script> Document.write("hello world") </script>
```

This is what it output ....

```
<Script> Document.write("hello world") </script>
```

The same thing.

Comment: Switch to `text` mode then write!

Comment: Whether the problem is in your browser or your code. We've none of 'em but your question. How can we help?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't put the code here.

Here is the code in my text Editor ..

<Script>

Document.write("hello world")

</script>

This is what it output ....

<Script>

Document.write("hello world")

</script>

The same thing.

Comment: Do not use uppercase in HTML tags. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19808514/1908141)

Comment: *Hey , am not using wordpress*. Then why are you posting here then ????. This site is for WordPress related issues only\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of issues in the code you have posted.

The script tag should be written properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Code
</script>
```

It is `document.write`, with a small case `d`. If your code is in a separate JavaScript file, then you can include it and mention the source in the `script` tag. If you're directly writing it in the `head` tag, please try with the proper syntax as I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Switch to Text Mode, as highlighted in image and write the JS code there in   tags.

Thanks

Comment: Hey , am not using wordpress. I'm using Notepad++ and Mozilla firefox

Comment: @Adetona77 in which WP file you are writing the code? If it is functions.php then are please tell me the action hook in which you are writing that.
Can you please tell me the filename

Comment: @Adetona77 Please explain why you post here if your question is not even WordPress related